# Why am I getting different output from the Alteryx R tool

Tags: r, alteryx

I using the Alteryx R Tool to sign an amazon http request. To do so, I need the hmac function that is included in the digest package.

I'm using a text input tool that includes the key and a datestamp.

```
Key= "foo"
datastamp= "20120215"
```

Here's the issue.  When I run the following script:

```
the.data <- read.Alteryx("1", mode="data.frame")
write.Alteryx(base64encode(hmac(the.data$key,the.data$datestamp,algo="sha256",raw = TRUE)),1)
```

I get an incorrect result when compared to when I run the following:

```
write.Alteryx(base64encode(hmac("foo","20120215",algo="sha256",raw = TRUE)),1)
```

The difference being when I hardcode the values for the key and object I get the correct result.  But if use the variables from the R data frame I get incorrect output.

Does the data frame alter the data in someway.  Has anyone come across this when working with the R Tool in Alteryx.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be that when creating the data frame, your character variables are converted to factors. The way to fix this with the `data.frame` constructor function is

```
the.data <- data.frame(Key="foo", datestamp="20120215", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I haven't used `read.Alteryx` but I assume it has a similar way of achieving this.

Alternatively, if your data frame has already been created, you can convert the factors back into character:

```
write.Alteryx(base64encode(hmac(
    as.character(the.data$Key),
    as.character(the.data$datestamp),
    algo="sha256",raw = TRUE)),1)
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo in my code. `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` does fix things in R.

Comment: I did some research and decided to try a Trim function.  That did the trick.  Do you know if being a factor would lead to whitespace?

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor `trim` isn't a base R function but I'm guessing it converts its argument to character. This is what fixes the problem, not whether there's whitespace.